# Activate jquery mobile html5 attributes code assist in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: jquery, html, aptana

i'm looking for a way to enable code assist or code completion in Aptana Studio 3 regarding jquery mobile specific html5 attributes like "data-transition="pop"".

I'm NOT looking for jquery mobile javascript code assist.